# Using most recent saved data with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am completing some items on a check list. I am counting the completed items using the following method:

```
- (NSUInteger)completedCount {
return [DIDTask MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completed == YES && list == %@", self]];
}
```

The problem I have is when I'm calling the method on a list - list.completedCount - immediately after the data is saved it does not give me the correct count but rather the value - 1. Only after when the app change screen for instance or display a pop-up (as per below), then list.completedCount gives me the correct value. But this is too late for me.

```
[UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Are you OK?" message:task.name cancelButtonTitle:@"Stop" otherButtonTitles:@[@"Yes", @"No"] handler:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
        if (buttonIndex > 0) {
            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                [[task MR_inContext:localContext] setCompletedValue:buttonIndex == 1];
            } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            }];
            [self continueAutomaticModeWithList:list taskIndex:index + 1];
        }
    }];
```

My question is how can I update or refresh the app immediately when the data is saved so that list.completedCount gives me the correct count right away?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work, because `[self continueAutomaticModeWithList:list taskIndex:index + 1];` is performed before the save completes. You have to move it to the completion block:

```
[UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Are you OK?" message:task.name cancelButtonTitle:@"Stop" otherButtonTitles:@[@"Yes", @"No"] handler:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex > 0) {
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            [[task MR_inContext:localContext] setCompletedValue:buttonIndex == 1];
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [self continueAutomaticModeWithList:list taskIndex:index + 1];
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks! Didn't even have to put the "weakSelf"... I went with "Self" directly and it worked. So is there any reason whyI should use "weakSelf" instead?

Comment: @Armand: You're right. None of the blocks is retained by `self`, so `__weak` modifier isn't needed here.